How can I access SSH from a cruise ship?
I took a cruise.  I purchased Internet access with my cruise so that I can service my clients if need be (Linux cloud servers).  The Internet access worked fine but wouldn't allow me to do SSH.  I suppose they must have it blocked.  I can't talk to any of their staff because no one knows what I mean by "SSH" or "port 22".
My question is, if I am provided with Internet access that works with HTTP and HTTPS (80 & 443), how can I access my servers over SSH?
chatGPT suggested a VPN - which I have.  Will that fix the problem?
Thanks!

If your VPN gateway is configured to accept connections at port 443, it may work. Especially if it is SSL-VPN. You mentioned you already have VPN available. What stops you from using it?

If you have a VPN already, why haven't you tried it yet?

This is a legitimate question.  Why is it down voted?

Of course I can try this and try that if I went on multiple cruises.  But I don't.  I was hoping someone had already tested and solved the problem and would be kind enough to share.

You don't need a VPN (although it might simplify some things).
Actually, you can use ssh as a VPN, but you still have the same problem: your provider is restricting the traffic, probably to just ports 80 and 443 for TCP.
Simplest solution is to just run a ssh server on port 80. However that needs an IP address which is NOT currently using port 80 for web traffic. OTOH HTTP AND TLS allow for multiplexing different hosts on the same IP/Port (using different mechanisms).
You could run squid in front of your webservers and use corkscrew to connect with ssh. Do make sure you are not running an open proxy!
I've never tried tunneling + multiplexing non-http traffic using TLS+SNI but that is exactly the problem SNI is intended to resolve. There are probably tools available off the shelf for this (I suspect someone may add details in comments or as a separate answer).
As an alternative, you might consider using noVNC.

Yes, a VPN should fix the problem if the ship's firewall is blocking SSH provided that the VPN supports SSH which I believe most do. although I can't imagine why they are blocking it in the first place. You could also use SSH over TOR described Here

Blocking port 22 can be about protecting the internal network from malicious attack. Routers etc may all have SSH configuration ports. While they should be properly locked down, it can be hard to garentee on a very large guest network so better for them to be safe.

It really depends on what is being blocked.
Worst case, you may have only ports 80 (HTTP), 443 (HTTPS), and 53 (DNS), and then through a web proxy and DNS server.  If this is the case, you would need a VPN designed to run over HTTP.
If it simply blocks everything but the three ports, but doesn't proxy them, then you could run an SSH daemon on one of those ports to allow you to remote login.
Assuming port 53 (DNS) is open or properly forwarded, it is possible to run a tunnel over that.  Look for a package called iodine and probably others.  (I can't claim to have used any, but the concept is an OLD internet legend.   I wouldn't expect much speed.)
VPN usage might be a problem, in that they might be blocking the ports it uses too.
Over course, the other problem with all these solutions is that you need to set them up at both ends, so unless you have a friend who has the security accesses on the mainland, you may have trouble.

Edit: Another idea.
There is a ProxyCommand directive in recent versions of OpenSSH.  If you read the documentation for it in ssh_config(5),
it tells how to use the directive and the OpenBSD version of netcat to proxy an SSH connection through an HTTP proxy server.  Even if you have an older or different version, it wouldn't be to difficult to hack into the SSH source.  This actually might work even in the "worst case" scenario.  And I would surprised in the worst case if they didn't provide this kind of proxy (as it is the only way for a user to get end-to-end encryption).

Thanks for the suggestions!  I am the admin on both ends so I can change anything needed.  My fear is that they're doing some sort of deep-packet inspection that'll even stop my use over port 80 et al.

I've seen that kind of thing done (though what I saw was only monitoring, not blocking).  It could be an issue, and would probably match the "worst case" I described.

Assuming you have an out-of-band solution for creating a website (maybe if you've a layover at a port during the cruise, or if there's a friend you can trust), you could install Apache Guacamole and access your systems through that. It's a web based Remote Desktop style interface - you connect to your instance of Guacamole using http/https, and it provides you an interface that maps through to your target system(s). Your local browser has no direct connection to the remote system.
